# Optimizing Table Creation in PHP PDO using Prepared Statements or Other

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to find a way to speed up MySQL Table Creation in PHP PDO. I'm using PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.

Each table is created with code similar to what you have below:

```
CREATE TABLE `moxedo`.`mox_config_8423` (`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `group_id` INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , `is_enabled` INT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , `tag` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL , `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `description` TEXT NOT NULL , `init_params` TEXT NOT NULL , `datetime_added` DATETIME NOT NULL , `datetime_lastmodified` DATETIME NOT NULL , `timestamp_univ` BIGINT(14) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) )
ENGINE = InnoDB; 
ALTER TABLE `moxedo`.`mox_config_8423` ADD UNIQUE `ix_u_tag_ad` ( `tag` );
```

I have about 120 of these dual-line queries to execute (so 240 queries in all). According to my benchmarks it takes 0.12 seconds for the `CREATE TABLE` bit, and 0.07 seconds for the `ALTER TABLE` bit. So it'll take about 24 seconds to complete if I run each query seperately.

Is there a way I can use prepared statements in PDO to execute all 240 queries at once i.e. using `PDO::prepare` for PHP. I'm just looking for a way to speed things up significantly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `mysql` storage engine. What are you actually using?

Comment: How many times do you have to execute this script? Usually tables are created only once, so execution time is not that important...

Comment: 24 seconds seem terribly long. I've seen install scripts create hundreds of tables and run thousands of queries take just a few seconds. I tend to believe there is an issue with your database server that needs to be resolved. I don't think prepared statements will save you.

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeHuberdeau It's highly unlikely that it is the database server, my inserts are super fast. Could it be a demerit with using PDO?!

Comment: If inserts are fast through PDO, I see no reason why it would make create statements slower. If you run the complete list of queries through the command line mysql command, does it get better?

Comment: Well, you can cut the amount of statements in half by moving `UNIQUE \`ix_u_tag_ad\` ( \`tag\`)`  into the `CREATE TABLE` statement... Why do you do that seperately? Would still take about the same amount of time on empty tables though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple approaches including concatenating SQL queries, I still did not get the performance improvement I wanted.

However, by switching away from PDO to MySQLi, I noticed that I got a significant performance improvement, albeit "on paper".

When I use PDO, the SQL query must execute the entire script before handing back control to the page. However, with MySQLi it somehow hands the SQL query off (to the background), and then sends control back to the page.

So instead of waiting 24 seconds to execute 120 tables, I wait for 0.1 second using MySQLi. It takes about the same time in theory (because if you use PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench you'll notice that it'll take a couple of seconds before all your tables are listed complete using `SHOW TABLES`), but because my script doesn't wait for the entire SQL query to execute before my page comes back, the user experience is better.

Also, being that it would likely take more than 30 seconds before I need to use the tables for anything anyway, I don't see any major disadvantages, plus your script just appears to be much quicker.

So, if you need to create a lot of tables with an install script, I would suggest not using PDO, use MySQLi instead. You should still use PDO if you're creating one table at a time, or for your other database tasks.

Thanks for all the contributions.

Comment: MySQLi does support asynchronous calls but that doesn't optimize any of the run speeds it just run the processes in parallel. There's no performance improvement and the downside is that you don't know if the query was successful or if it's over by the time you send the user a "installation confirmed" screen. And the user might try to actually use the application even though there are several more seconds he needs to wait until the DDLs finish.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I understand that, but what else can I do to speed things up, 24 seconds is too long for the tables to install in my script. Plus, I figure I can use a multi-step process to slow the user down gracefully, and then do a final check of the tables in the last step. Other than that, I'm not sure what else to do to optimize table creation.

Comment: That's precisely how you should use the async feature: alow the user to do something else in the meantime and block only when there is nothing more to do (from the user's pov). Async is definitely an improvement, I'm just saying it's got its downsides.

Answer (score 3):

Prepared statements allow you to basically treat a statement like a stored function or a procedure.

Meaning you define the prepared statement the call it multiple times with different parameters.

It does not allow you to parametrize table names or column names or keywords, just values (for filtering, sorting, inserting, updating etc.).

Hence the prepared statement can do precisely diddly squat for performance. On the contrary you have to do 2 operations `PREPARE` and `EXEC` which might actually end up slowing things down (only a bit).

Transactions in any database system do not do anything for improving speed. On the contrary they decrease speed. It's a price you have to pay for what they do which is ensuring either all of the data is in correctly or none at all, there's no `halfway there` state. If something fails it cleans everything up as if it hadn't even tried anything.

Also transactions in MySQL have no effect on DDL (data definition language) which means `CREATE` and `ALTER` statements are not held in a transactional mode but executed immediately.

Now that we cleared all the mist away we can answer the question:

- Concatenate all queries into one big query;
- Avoid repeatedly connecting to the DB for each query; Each communication takes time;
- Don't use `$pdo->startTransaction();` / `$pdo->commit();` use `START TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` directly in the SQL code;
- Run all queries in one go;
- If possible don't generate the query with PHP;
- Write it to a file perhaps use PHP for table prefixes and other small text snippets;
- Don't expect SQL code generated by inspecting the structure of ORMs or Reflection on classes to be as fast as most application installers which have a file containing all of the structures needed for the install;

As an example of code **you** might run before packing the application for deployment (suggestions 1, 6):

```
$table_queries = '';
foreach($table_names AS $table_name) {
    $table_queries .= function_that_generates_table_query($table_name);
}
file_put_contents('all_table_creates_qeries.sql', $table_queries);
```

As an example of code your **deployers** / **users** might run when the application is installing itself (suggestions 2, 4, 5):

```
$table_queries = file_get_contents('all_table_creates_qeries.sql');
$pdo->exec($table_queries);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any code snippets for No.1 (Concatenate) and No.4 (Run all queries) of your answer?!

Comment: Thanks for the code snippets. I didn't see any improvements using PDO so I went with MySQLi instead. I posted an answer on this. Cheers.